# Ruby Install Puppet Vagrant

Tags: ruby, vagrant, puppet

I tried to install ruby on my vagrant machine with puppet, in the puppet file define a ruby class with package ruby:

```
class ruby {
package { "ruby":
    ensure => '1.9.1'
}
```

But when run the vagrant machine, get error that the version is not found and installs 1.8.7.

When i run  `ralsh package` list the version of ruby:

```
package { 'ruby1.8':
 ensure => '1.8.7.352-2ubuntu1.6',
}
```

So, how can upgrade my ruby version? I'm new in this stuff of puppet & vagrant. Is there a way within vagrant or puppet?

Thanks.

Comment: What base image are you using? In Debian, there used to be a `ruby1.9.3` package that could coexist with `ruby1.8`. I suppose that your version of Ubuntu still has that. Install it instead of the `ruby` metapackage.

Comment: Ubuntu Precise 12.04. So, the only way is install it without puppet or vagrant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [database](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ruby&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all), `precise` had no Ruby `1.9` packaging whatsoever.

On this platform, you will need to add a repository for some `ruby1.9.3` or similar packages.

It will likely be much easier to just switch to a base image of a more current OS.